# SDWebImage and Swift

Tags: swift, typedef, sdwebimage

I've succeeded in incorporating `SDWebImage` (written in `Objective-C`) with my `Swift` project - but its still acting a bit funny. Specifically, its giving me an error in the `if` statement inside the following `Closure`:

```
    let completionBlock: SDWebImageCompletionBlock! = { 
        (image:UIImage!, error: NSError!, cacheType:SDImageCacheType, imageURL:NSURL!) -> Void in

        if (image && cacheType == SDImageCacheType.SDImageCacheTypeNone) {
            cell.productImageView.alpha = 0.0
            UIView.animateWithDuration(1.5, animations: {
                cell.productImageView.alpha = 1.0
            })
        }
    }

    cell.productImageView.sd_setImageWithURL(imageURL!, placeholderImage:UIImage(named:"Icon120pix.png"), completed: completionBlock)
```

The error I'm getting on that if statement is: `Use of unresolved identifier 'SDImageCacheTypeNone'`

This makes no sense because `SDImageCacheTypeNone` is one of the values defined in the `SDImageCacheType typedef`.

By the way, if I take that `if` statement out and leave just the statements inside it, everything works just fine.

So any ideas what I might be doing wrong here?

Comment: That worked. So is that a Swift thing? The Typedef is called `SDImageCacheType`, and its values are `SDImageCacheTypeNone`, `SDImageCacheTypeDisk`, and `SDImageCacheTypeMemory`.  So because each value _contains_ the name of the typedef itself you just use the part that's different? Meaning `None`, `Disk`, and `Memory`?  Or is Objective-C like that too and I just didn't know that?

Comment: Got it. Thanks!  (why not post your comment as an answer so I can mark it as correct and give you credit for it?)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Have a look at this document in the `Enumerations` section for a more in depth explanation as to why Swift displays Objective-C enums differently.

[Apple Swift Documents](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/BuildingCocoaApps/InteractingWithCAPIs.html)

In your code example the way to solve the problem is to use:

```
SDImageCacheType.None
```

Instead of

```
SDImageCacheType.SDImageCacheTypeNone
```